# Wordpress Blog Archive page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to make a archive page for my blog.

I have my wordpress installation at: domain.com,
The blog is on domain.com/blog
and all other pages / custom post types are working from the root

For instance I have a custom post type for clients, this cpt works on domain.com/clients with a for archive-clients.php an overview page.

Now I'm trying to make a same page for the blog but nothing is working.
The only thing that works is my index.php.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to create a file named archive.php

EDIT: more info below

If you want to have a special link for the /blog page create an extra template:

Wordpress looks for the template name to index page template listings. Example:

```
/*  
  Template Name: Blog Archive  
*/
```

Technically, you can copy the code from the index.php or archive.php, create another file, put the copied code in it, and at the very top of the file inside of opening and closing php tags have template name code. This will allow you to create a new page named blog (or anything else) in the wordpress admin area, then you can assign it to a template named blog archive.

More information:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: I have this page but that is not working. Also when I remove the blog page under pages I get my 404 page.

Comment: I don't think you understand it. I know how to use this, it works for my custom post types and other pages with templates. The only page where it doesn't work is the blog page, it looks like it can't work like this method.

Comment: That is very weird.

Another possibility is the create a page-blog.php if you have a slug called blog then wordpress will automatically render it (if you have it set to the default template) You may also want to check your site settings and see if you have the blog or archive page set to be the front page, because that may be overriding everything.

Comment: It's working, I had to make a page-blog.php and a page called blog. Now I have a overview on the page-blog.php with all the blog posts. Thanks @elev !